# Consignment Tracking in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am new to Magento, but and an experienced developer. I am setting up Magento for my own storefront. We sell antique maps. Some of these maps are sold on consignment from local dealers. We have a retail store and online ecommerce site, but are transitioning to Magento.

Direct question: What is the best way to track products sold on consignment? On the back end, I will need to know who the consignor is and what commission rate he/she earns on the sale. Is this possible in Magento through an existing extension or configuring a sales rep type extension to meet our needs?

Comment: Hi Pissah and welcome to MageOverflow. I think your question is quite broad and therefore will be closed soon. I don't know any extension what is doing what you need, but I'm sure there exists at least one.

Comment: Hi Fabian. Thank you for the response. How about we change the question to: How would I customize my Magento so that I can assign an item in an order to a user (customer) with a commission rate? Second question, how to get a report of how must that user earned?